# Option windows in ArcGIS clipped out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, installation, windows-8.1

I recently started using 10.2.2 in my new laptop and I'm having trouble in the 'pop-up windows' like the option windows inside the application (pls see the attached figure). The options windows are not displayed fully so many of the items are clipped on the bottom. Please look at the attached figure, there is a whole lot of option clipped at the bottom. There is no scroll-bar and I cannot resize those windows. Reducing the windows font (to 100%) didn't help. I reinstalled it, changed resolution of the windows but it didn't help. This problem is not seen in other application like photoshop but only in esri applications (ArcMap, ArcScene etc.)

Is there anybody facing this problem or has any solution?
I have Dell XPS 15 with windows 8.1 and I use 1920x1080 resolution.

[image]

Comment: Try to change screen resolutions and see what happens?

Comment: Are you able to hit TAB to go through the options on the pop-up window?